# MySQL Server on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host 100+ Wordpress websites on Azure. For that I would need MySQL databases and I am confused which route I should go. With quick google search, I found mainly three options

1. Use MySQL Preview (which is not good for production environment)
2. Purchase costly third party subscription by ClearDB or Bitnami
3. Set UP windows/Linux VM and host LAMP Server on it. Host MySQL server there.  I am just trying to know if there are any other better options. Thank you.

Update: One primary requirement I have is those wordpress websites are already created and I am migrating them to new hosting. I need separate database for each Word press site.

Comment: @BenV, I read that link. It doesn't add to anything I doesn't know so far. If you have experience in this what would you suggest? I need to migrate 112 Wordpress websites to Azure and have single MySQL server for all of them.

Comment: My point was that there are currently no other options, but there are lots of people who want the option of a MySQL DB-as-a-Service offering.